# React and ExpandedRow Render in Ant-design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design table in which I am using row expanded functionality. my query is when I click any row of the table the row is opening but the issue is when i click on other row the previous row still open, I just want such functionality in which if I click any row the other which is already open should close..... if any one have solution please show me demo in stackBlitz..... Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the antd docs [AntD/#expandable](https://ant.design/components/table/#expandable).

Its simple. AntD tables have parameter `expandable` that accepts many variables such as `expandedRowKeys` that holds witch of the rows have been expanded and `onExpand` that is  amethod that gets called when you click the icon to expand it. A simple way would be to create your own variable to hold the key that is expanded like so

```
const [expandedKey, setExpandedKey] = useState(null);
```

And create a new method for when the row is being expanded as so

```
const onExpand = (_, { key }) => setExpandedKey(key);
```

Then when rendering a AntD table pass these variables

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  expandable={{
    expandedRowRender: (record) => (
      <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
    ),
    onExpand: onExpand,
    expandedRowKeys: [expandedKey]
  }}
  dataSource={data}
/>
```

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-http-jxf1m?file=/src/App.js

---

**EDIT**

To make it close whenever clicking the `_` icon (when its open), change the `onExpand` method to this:

```
const onExpand = (_, { key }) =>
    expandedKey === key ? setExpandedKey(null) : setExpandedKey(key);
```

---

Comment: if we want to click on  '_' icon the row should be collapse ... can you please give any solution

Comment: @MujtabaHussainBhat I updated the same Demo link to include it so whenever you click the `_` icon that it would close. Basically it just a change to the `onExpand` method to include a check if its expanded or not. If it is - set state to `null`. If its not - set state to the `key`

Comment: once again Thank you so much.. i appreciated for your help